# Backbone collection fetch not populating in Jasmine + Sinon spec

Tags: backbone.js, fetch, jasmine, sinon

When I run this spec output I get "Expected 0 to equal 2." 2 is the correct length of model objects in my fixture so Sinon's fakeServer is responding properly with the mocked response. I can't figure out why my Collection has zero objects after fetch then. Any help would be really appreciated!

FYI: this is coming from following along the Backbone Sinon + Jasmine tutorial here: http://tinnedfruit.com/2011/03/25/testing-backbone-apps-with-jasmine-sinon-2.html

Spec:

```
describe "Todos collection", ->

  describe "when fetching models from the server", ->
    beforeEach ->
      @todo = sinon.stub(window, "Todo")
      @todos = new Todos()
      @fixture = @fixtures.Todos.valid
      @server = sinon.fakeServer.create()
      @server.respondWith "GET", "/todos", @validResponse(@fixture)

    afterEach ->
      @todo.restore()
      @server.restore()

    it "should parse todos from the response", ->
      @todos.fetch()
      @server.respond()
      expect(@todos.length).toEqual @fixture.response.todos.length
```

Model:

```
class window.Todos extends Backbone.Collection
  model: window.Todo
  url: "/todos"
  comparator: (todo) ->
    todo.get('priority')
  parse: (res) ->
    res.response.todos
```

## EDIT:

Buck Doyle below has helped me see there is no spec problem. I have some kind of issue with my Jasmine Headless Webkit config, and if the specs are run with Jasmine standalone they pass.

Comment: anyone have a link to what the @ syntax means?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Theory: you need to wait for the “server” to respond to the request before checking for the result. Mocking the response isn’t enough: the `fetch` is still asynchronous.

Try a `waits` or a more complicated-but-elegant `waitsFor` as described at https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Asynchronous-specs

Comment: I wish it were so but adding `waits(5000)` (preposterous even) doesn't help. Thanks though!

Comment: Hmm. I tried to replicate it in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/buckdoyle/4H3Jv/1/) and it works for me. Can you share more of your implementation?

Comment: Thanks Buck!! Your jsfiddle has helped me quit a bit. I've forked it and updated it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mCNcC/1/). This is my complete implementation include functions pulled in from helpers. The specs pass! The only difference I can think of is that I'm using Jasmine Headless Webkit. This is a really good push in the right direction