# Unable to populate Backbone collection with sinon + jasmine

Tags: backbone.js, jasmine, sinon

I have the same problem that was asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509708/backbone-collection-fetch-not-populating-in-jasmine-sinon-spec)

the author of the question mentioned that he was able to solve it by using the standalone version of jasmine over the headless webkit. 
In my tests i use only a standalone version of jasmine and still having the same problem.
Here is my code:

```
describe 'Shared Collections Specs', ->
  describe 'Channel Collection', ->
    describe 'When fetching channels', ->
      responseFixture = null
      channelCollection = null
      server = null

      beforeEach ->
        channelCollection = new ChannelCollection()
        responseFixture = [{id: 3, name: 'foo'}, {id: 1, name: 'bar'}, {id: 2, name: 'baz'}]
        server = sinon.fakeServer.create()
        server.respondWith('GET', 'enspoint/channels', [
          200, {'Content-Type':'application/json'}, JSON.stringify responseFixture
        ])

      afterEach ->
        server.restore()

      it 'should populate the collection', ->
        channelCollection.fetch()
        server.respond()
        expect(channelCollection.length).toEqual responseFixture.length
```

The collection is always empty insted of expected length of 3 it fails with `Expected 0 to equal 3.`
I tried to use jasmine `waits` and `runs` as i thought there might be something async in the process but i'm getting the same result.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you also post your Backbone model code?

Answer (score 1):

Just an innocent observation, but there might be a typo in the URL "enspoint/channels" in your XHR fixture.  For example, did you mean "endpoint/channels"?